# how to extract a specific pattern of entity from a given input string in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a dataset like this.

```
id  StringToExtract description
 3  ddlsql144   fotrscomi.srsrelvqe.2008.agentjob.jobduration na fotrscomi.srsrelvqe.2008.agentjob:ddlsql144.internal.ecnahcdroffilc.net;mssrsrelvqe;srsrelvqeagent;{d96c51f7-0e2b-4e9d-9e29-853f29d99598} ddlsql144.internal.ecnahcdroffilc.net;mssrsrelvqe;srsrelvqeagent true 255 1 1 inc0419975 na performancecollection uk\929666 03-04-2017 08:09 03-05-2017 00:09 57600 ddldonmocs
 7  ddlsql43    fotrscomi.srsrelvqe.2000.agent:ddlsql43.internal.ecnahcdroffilc.net;pre;sqlagent$pre ddlsql43.internal.ecnahcdroffilc.net;pre false 255 1 1 chg0017294 na eventcollection uk\926944 3-21-2017 8:47:40 pm 3-21-2017 8:51:14 pm 214 ddldonmocs
13  ddlsql43    fotrscomi.srsrelvqe.2000.agent:ddlsql43.internal.ecnahcdroffilc.net;pre;sqlagent$pre ddlsql43.internal.ecnahcdroffilc.net;pre false 255 1 1 chg0017294 na eventcollection system 3-13-2017 2:29:53 pm 3-13-2017 2:30:20 pm 26 ddldonmocs
```

this is how my training dataset looks. I would like to extract the same pattern of string for my future data too.

I had checked about regular expression, pattern recognition but, I'm stumped and don't know how to proceed. any help on the approach will do.

Comment: try finding `re.search(r'\bddlsql\d+\b', desc)`. This should give you the `ddlsqlnnn` from the desc. run it on whole column using map.

Comment: Thansk.. it works. I have one more pattern like this hkg-exr-01,esc-pf-01
how do i extract a pattern like this. I tried something like this re.search(r'\b\w-\w-\d+\b', a), but not getting any macthes

Comment: try `(r'\b\w+-\w+-\d+\b', a)`

Comment: Thanks..it works..

Comment: see my answer for better choice of regex and some explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`re.search(r'\bddlsql\d+\b', a)`

**explanation**

```
\b             #start with word boundary. So that it is not part of another word.
ddlsql         #server name pattern
\d+            #one or more digits
\b             #word boundary
```

`re.search` returns the first occurance of the above string pattern.

For second pattern
`r'(?i)\b[A-Z]+-[A-Z]+-\d+\b'`

```
(?i)     #ignore case
\b       #Word boundary
[A-Z]+-  #Words with one or more alphabets only followed by -
[A-Z]+-  #Same as above second set
\d+      #one or more digits
\b       #word boundary
```

Comment: when i try this re.search(r"\b\w+-\w+-\d+\b", desc). It returns output like <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(37, 47), match='hkg-exr-01'> how can i just extract the value from the output and append it to a list.

Comment: @sruthi `re.search(reg, s).group(0)`